# Using GAE datastore relationship vs flat kind design

Tags: google-app-engine, data-modeling, google-cloud-datastore

We have a requirement to implement in GAE datastore. There are set of documents (in millions) and each document has a owner, some comments and revisions associated with it.

If the owner of document is leaving the organization, then we need to change the ownership of the document to the person who did last revision. Also we need to retain the revisions and comments for each document. This ownership change is to be implemented by a job which will process each and every document one by one.

Is it the right approach to have Parent-Child relationships between the entities Document,Comment and Revision like Document is the parent with Comment and Revision as its child? OR in typical NoSql way we need to flatten the table and make a single entity?

The typical NoSQL implementation needs only insert and read but no updates. Is this the way the Google datastore works? Please clarify.

Our research says that we can have relationship but that will look more like RDBMS.

Comment: This question is far too broad.  You should try modelling and protoyping. The come back with some specific implementation questions.
If you are going to have owned relationships that can be changed **do not** define this with parents defined in the key. This means you can't change ownership, but you then have to copy and create new entities.
  Tree and  relationships are fine, the important thing is looking at your access patterns and optimising entities for the activity.  If your queries would normally imply joins then intermediate entities that store everything you need become important.

Comment: Can we see your document format, edited into the question? Personally I think the schema-less format promoted by NoSQL causes more problems than it solves - so unless you need the raw speed of NoSQL, go with a traditional RDBMS and model this using tables.

Comment: @halfer except I wouldn't class the datastore as schema-less

Comment: Fair enough @Tim, thanks - not my area. I agree this is too broad as it stands, hope the OP comes back to amend it!

Answer (score 1):

To choose proper schema design, you should clarify how you plan to work with data and keep in mind datastore limitations. In brief:

1. NoSql approach (single entity)

   - one update per second per entity group
   - you read and write the whole entity every time (except for projection queries)
2. Parent-child relations (ancestor relationships)

   - cannot be changed in future
   - form single entity-group so you achieve strong consistency while reading the query
   - one update per second per entity group! (So if you have a case with lots of live comments this wont work for you)
3. RDBMS approach (tables and relations)

   - datastore has no joins on multiple tables (so only split data in tables where you are not intending to query together)
   - eventually consistent reads

Comment: This is a good answer rather spoiled by the addition of txtspk. Please don't do this - readers whose first language is not English have a hard time enough as it is, and readers whose first language _is_ English might get annoyed reading it. I can't imagine many milliseconds are saved by typing `you` rather than `u`. Thanks!

Comment: @Ramiel, thanks for the response, my doubt is if we are in No Sql arena and we should flatten the table then why google documentation for GAE datastore talks of relationships and hierarchies even though that also can be flattened. [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships)

Comment: Because flattening has limitations (as i mentioned every approach has pros and cons): one update per second (imagine post with fast growing likes or smth), data duplication, etc.